# Opening KORG Files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

does anyone know how I can use NAudio or any other library to open KORG files such as .PCM and .PRF? I cannot seem to find any tutorials anywhere. By open I mean read data from the files such as sample rate and be able to play them.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: These aren't common formats, so I doubt there's a library than handles them, but I think you can find the format description on the web, it shouldn't be too complicated to implement

Comment: Can you explain further please? How would I go about opening a file in C# with an exotic file type? BinaryReader?

Comment: Yes with a binary reader. You just have to follow the description of the format. For example if the first 4 bytes give the frequency rate (44.1khz for example) you just have to read them and store the value somewhere, and so on. Since PCM is an uncompressed format it won't be too much trouble. But the thing is, PCM also seems to be a raw format, which means it can have no headers to tell you how it is encoded... Where do you get these files from? Do you have more info about each of them?

Comment: It was sent from a client. I tried reading it using DataReader but all I got was jumbled text, as it was encoded. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I think you need more information from your client, at least you need to know the "frame rate" for PCM files, I don't know about PRF ones. If you don't know the format you can't do much about it.